# Hide cursor from objects on the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

I want to hide my mouse cursor whenever someone goes over the `object` tag. But `cursor:none` is not working for objects while it works with rest of the page.

Here is what i am using but i am failing do it.

```
<object id="obj" class="obj" style="cursor:none;" data='bla-bla.pdf' 
    type='application/pdf' 
    width='1000px' 
    height='640px'>
```

`cursor:none` is not working. Please tell me any way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried putting the object in a `<div>` and applying the cursor style on the `<div>`?  Just a thought...I avoid using `<object>` tags, so this is a shot in the dark.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but that also isnt working.

Comment: @EthanBrown that wouldn't work as long as the object is in there.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an overlay; `<object>`s can act funny.

HTML:

```
<div id="obj_container">
    <object id="obj" src="blablabla.pdf"></object>
    <div id="obj_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#obj_container{
    position:relative;
}
#obj{
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
    z-index:2;cursor:none;
}
```

See this **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/Hy24c/1/)** for more complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try using div:

Your HTML:

```
<div style="cursor:none;">
    <object id="obj" class="obj" data='bla-bla.pdf' type='application/pdf' 
     width='1000px' height='640px'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBv22/

It applies a mask over the object element where you specify `cursor:none`.

The only issue is if you need the object to be clickable/interacted with. Depending on your targeted browsers (modern, IE11+), you could add `pointer-events: none` to address that.

http://caniuse.com/pointer-events